# Send e-mail using gmail and Indy

Tags: delphi, ssl, gmail, indy

I am trying to send an e-mail from Delphi using gmail.
I have Indy 10.5.9.0 and Delphi XE3.

I got example code from:
http://www.andrecelestino.com/delphi-xe-envio-de-e-mail-com-componentes-indy/

I also tried other example codes but with same results.

I have libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll from here:
http://www.andrecelestino.com/wp-content/files/DLLs-SSL-DelphiXE.rar
but I also tried:
http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/openssl-1.0.2d-i386-win32.zip
with no luck.

My code (FULL):

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection,
  IdTCPClient, IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase, IdMessageClient, IdSMTPBase, IdMessage,
  IdSMTP, IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket, IdIOHandlerStack, IdSSL, IdSSLOpenSSL, IdText;






procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  // variáveis e objetos necessários para o envio
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  IdSMTP: TIdSMTP;
  IdMessage: TIdMessage;
  IdText: TIdText;
  sAnexo: string;
begin
  // instanciação dos objetos
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocket := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(Self);
  IdSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(Self);
  IdMessage := TIdMessage.Create(Self);

  try
    // Configuração do protocolo SSL (TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL)
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocket.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocket.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;

    // Configuração do servidor SMTP (TIdSMTP)
    IdSMTP.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocket;
    IdSMTP.UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS;
    IdSMTP.AuthType := satDefault;
    IdSMTP.Port := 465;
    IdSMTP.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
    IdSMTP.Username := 'MYLOGIN@gmail.com';
    IdSMTP.Password := 'MYPASS';

    // Configuração da mensagem (TIdMessage)
    IdMessage.From.Address := 'MYLOGIN@gmail.com';
    IdMessage.From.Name := 'John Smith';
    IdMessage.ReplyTo.EMailAddresses := IdMessage.From.Address;
    IdMessage.Recipients.Add.Text := 'receiver@example.com';
    IdMessage.Subject := 'Hello World';
    IdMessage.Encoding := meMIME;

    // Configuração do corpo do email (TIdText)
    IdText := TIdText.Create(IdMessage.MessageParts);
    IdText.Body.Add('The body of the e-mail goes here');
    IdText.ContentType := 'text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1';


    // Conexão e autenticação
    try
      IdSMTP.Connect;
      IdSMTP.Authenticate;
    except
      on E:Exception do
      begin
        MessageDlg('Cannot authenticate: ' +
          E.Message, mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);
        Exit;
      end;
    end;

    // Envio da mensagem
    try
      IdSMTP.Send(IdMessage);
      MessageDlg('Message sent successfully!', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
    except
      On E:Exception do
      begin
        MessageDlg('Error while sending a message: ' +
          E.Message, mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    // liberação dos objetos da memória
    FreeAndNil(IdMessage);
    FreeAndNil(IdSSLIOHandlerSocket);
    FreeAndNil(IdSMTP);
  end;
end;
```

But I only get this error from Gmail:

https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1sdf[...] Please log in via your web browser and
then try again.
 Learn more at
 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 t1sm2526415lcc.25 - gsmtp

I did log on https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1sdf[...] but I didn't tell me anything really.

Comment: If you don't find any better solution then take a look at this demo working on Lazarus: http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,28951.0.html

Comment: Hi. Any news on this? Do you have some working code?

Comment: @Gravity The code is fine. You can read below how to change Google settings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was because Google blocked login this way. 
So after spending 10 hours triple checking every possible setting in my code I found this page:

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

and enabled access for "less secure apps".

**UPDATE:**

After that try to send an e-mail with Delphi and then if it fails log into your Gmail account and visit these 2 pages:

https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity

https://myaccount.google.com/secureaccount

and confirm this new "unknown device" is you (it's your Delphi app).

Comment: You enabled 2-factor authentication in your Google account. That is a good thing, it makes the account more secure. But it also requires an SMTP SASL-based authentication scheme that Indy does not support yet (OAuth2). There are some third-party implementations floating around. In any case, you do not need to enable "less secure apps", you just need to generate an [application password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) and use that in the `TIdSMTP.Password` property instead of your actual Google password.

Comment: I did not enable 2-factor authentication as this is a new gmail account. And since I want the program to work with other people's gmail accounts this generating password is a bit complicated. Also Google should return an error that explains what's wrong and it didn't. You are now just a devils advocate.

Comment: Did you read the rest of Remy's comment? Specifically "*Indy does not support yet (OAuth2)*"

Comment: @JerryDodge This doesn't matter. Gmail used to provide a standard SSL SMTP without any problems. And then they stopped. You can still use it if you enable "less secure apps" on your Google account. So you don't have to use OAuth2. Gmail should return an error like "We blocked SSL SMTP. Switch to OAuth2 or enable it back on your accounts". Instead they just return a link which doesn't explain a thing.

Comment: @Tom You said "And since I want the program to work with other people's gmail accounts this generating password is a bit complicated." which suggests you're looking for a solution which will work in either case without requiring your users to make changes to their accounts. OAuth2 does that.

Comment: @JerryDodge It's 6 steps on https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en . Enabling "less secure" is way simpler.

Comment: @Tom Yes, I've done this before. However, are you wanting to make it easier for you to code or easier for your users? I personally would despise any software which required me to modify my account to be less secure. I highly appreciate the 2 step verification process, and wish more services would go that way to keep personal data safe. Remember, a gmail account also authenticates all Google services.