# How can I send email through google security?

Tags: delphi, smtp, gmail

I have developed an app for Android and iOS.  I am using Delphi 10.2.3 Tokyo, with Indy 10.

I wrote a function for sending an email via Gmail with some help.

Although the function often works properly, sometimes it gets the error below when some participants log in Gmail with their own phones.

> https://accounts.google.com/signIn/continue?sarp=1&scc=1sdf[...] Please log in via your web browser and then try again. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 y4-v6sm15938458pgy.18 - gsmtp

I have already seen [Send e-mail using gmail and Indy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776715/), but I don't understand how I should use `TIdSMTP.Password`.

How should I revise my function to avoid this error?

The code is below.

```
type
  TIdSMTPAccess = class(TIdSMTP)
  end;

procedure MailSend; 
var
  IdSMTP: TIdSMTP;
  Msg: TIdMessage;
begin 
  IdSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
  try
    SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdSMTP);
    IdSMTP.IOHandler := SSL;

    IdSMTP.Host     := 'smtp.gmail.com';
    IdSMTP.Port     := 587;
    IdSMTP.Username := 'xxxx@gmail.com';
    IdSMTP.Password := 'xxxx';
    IdSMTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS; 

    TIdSMTPAccess(IdSMTP).IPVersion := Id_IPv6; 
    try 
      IdSMTP.Connect; 
    except 
      TIdSMTPAccess(IdSMTP).IPVersion := Id_IPv4; 
      try
        IdSMTP.Connect; 
      except
        // unable to connect!
        Exit;
      end;
    end; 

    try
      Msg := TIdMessage.Create(nil); 
      try 
        Msg.OnInitializeISO           := IdMessage_InitializeISO; 
        Msg.ContentType               := 'text/plain'; 
        Msg.CharSet                   := 'UTF-8'; 
        Msg.ContentTransferEncoding   := 'BASE64'; // BASE64 (7bit) 
        //Msg.ContentTransferEncoding   := '8bit';   // RAW(8bit) 
        Msg.From.Name                 := SsNoSt; 
        Msg.From.Address              := 'xxxx@gmail.com'; 
        Msg.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'xxxx@gmail.com'; 
        Msg.Subject                   := SsNoSt; 
        Msg.Body.Text                 := 'Unicode String (body)'; 

        IdSMTP.Send(Msg); 
      finally 
        Msg.Free; 
      end; 
    finally
      IdSMTP.Disconnect;
    end;
  finally 
    IdSMTP.Free; 
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: You have two choices: 1) enable "Less secure apps" in your Gmail settings, and then use your real Gmail password in `TIdSMTP.Password`, or 2) disable "Less secure apps" in Gmail, and then have Gmail generate an [application-specific password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) that you can use in `TIdSMTP.Password`.

Comment: @Remy Thank you for giving me advices. First one, you mean enable "Less secure apps" and use my gmail password at `IdSMTP.Password := 'xxxx';` in my function? If it is right, I already do it. But some gets error of `78754`. In second one, you mean disable  "Less secure apps" and write another password at `IdSMTP.Password := 'xxxx';`? I will try both.

Comment: I know for a fact that app-specific passwords work with `TIdSMTP`, because that is what I use on my own Gmail account. And besides, nobody really likes the idea of having to enable the "less secure apps" option in their Gmail account, so you shouldn't force that on your users.

Comment: @Remy I appreciate to hear your experience. I tried second one to write another password at IdSMTP.Password := 'xxxx'; to IdSMTP.Password := 'aaaa';. However, I got an error below. 'Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCrecentials y18-v6sm9596377pfl.90 - smtp'. How should I revise my code?

Comment: You can't just use any arbitrary password you want.  You MUST go into your Gmail settings and have Gmail **generate a password** for you to use.  Did you not read the [page I linked to earlier](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)? Especially the section on "How to generate an App password".

Comment: @Remy Thank you for your advices. I could generate an app password and it works fine in my Android phone. Next I will confirm whether it works in iOS.